# Why this pattern - Span tags with class enclosing img in Lightning Design System?

Tags: css, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I was checking out the new Lightning Design System framework from Salesforce, and noticed there's a pattern of img tags inside of span tags. Reference link - https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/images/

Example code:

```
<span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar--x-small">
    <img src="/assets/images/avatar2.jpg" alt="person name" />
</span>
```

Any ideas why they're using this pattern in LDS putting a class on an enclosing span img tag vs adding the class directly to img? The CSS doesn't appear to be dependent on a span selector.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a "definitive" answer, but it's one that seems logical to me. The Lightning Design System uses a CSS grid system or what many think of as a flexi-page. With a `<span` tag, the image will more readily float/adjust to accommodate variations in page sizes. If the CSS were inside the `img` selector, it wouldn't do that.

The LDS CSS needs to be able to detect the specific tags they're meant to act on while also adjusting to page size changes. In the example you cite, `img` is a child of `<span>`, the `<span>` can adjust with changes to the grid without disrupting the remainder of the intended attributes in the CSS a designer wants to have applied to that tag. If the CSS were in the `<img>` tag, many of it's attributes might change when accommodations are made for changes in the grid because of the device displaying the page.